# Cannot run 'heroku local': cannot find bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler, procfile

I'm trying to run the new `heroku local` command that is part of the heroku toolkit, detailed here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local

I've set up a simple Procfile for my Ruby on Rails app:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
```

The local server fails to launch; it appears that it cannot find installed gems:

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs'





                                                                         : Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, dotenv-0.7.0, foreman-0.63.0
, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, mime-types-1.23, minitest-2.5.1, rack-1.5.2, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.5, rest-client-1.6.7, sequel-3.20.0, sinatra-1.0, taps-0.3.24,
 thor-0.18.1] (Gem::LoadError)
```

I have run `bundle install`, so is forego looking in the wrong place? How can I correct this?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you are using command prompt?

Comment: @PareshGami Yes. Is that a problem? I'm running windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use git-bash command prompt.

Git-bash is installed as part of Git for Windows. You can download and install Git for Windows [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Comment: huh? `git base` is a git command, not a standalone command prompt... ? I already have git installed.

Comment: Got it. Using `git-bash` worked a charm, thanks. I'm going to update your answer.